# How to add class dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an class to an closest element of an click object.

If you see code below, **I would like to add an class to `.process-signs-direction-cover-button`**

There is an loop, so the above classes get's repeated. But I want to add an classes to `closest()` `.process-signs-direction-cover-button` of where I click.

See picture

[image]

MY php:

```
                <div class="col-md-6 reduced_padding_col7">
            <?php
                $signs_to_direction_and_cover_process = $mysqli_scs->query("SELECT * FROM agsigns_db3.stock_stk where idstc_stk = ".$row['idstc_stk']." AND directioncolor_stk = 'Yellow' ");
                $row_cnt = $signs_to_direction_and_cover_process->num_rows;



                if($row_cnt > 0){ 

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($signs_to_direction_and_cover_process)) { ?>

                    <div class="col-md-4 thumbnail"><img src="../../css/sign-directions/<?php echo $row['directionimage_stk']; ?>" class="processing-signs-direction-cover-sign-direction-selection-process" id="<?php echo $row['id_stk']; ?>" />
                            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center signs-text">
                                <span class="current_stock_figure">
                                        <?php echo $row['stock_stk'] == ""  ? "N/A" : $row['stock_stk']; ?>
                                </span> 
                                    <span class="max_stock_figure">
                                        <?php echo $row['maxlevel_stk']; ?>
                                    </span>
                            </div>
                    </div>


                <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 process-button">
                <img src="../../css/buttons/process-signs-covered-disabled.png" id="" class="process-signs-direction-cover-button disabled_button" rel="<?php echo $row['signcode_sgn']; ?>" alt="covered"/>

            <div class="options-remember-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="rememberoptions" name="rememberoption" value="checked" > Remember Options<br>
            </div>
```

MY JQuery

```
$(".processing-signs-direction-cover-sign-direction-selection-process").click(function() {

        $(this).closest("process-button.process-signs-direction-cover-button").toggleClass("process");


     });
```

**Modify** 
**Question Modified** 
[Image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYRVz.png)

Comment: `$(this).closest("process-button.process-signs-direction-cover-button").addClass("process");`

Comment: Just a tip, your HTML has your PHP code in there, for your question it wouldn't be required and just makes answering a lot harder.  What you can do though is copy the rendered HTML and paste here.  It would also make it so users could even create a Snippet from it.

Comment: `closest` means the closest ancestor. Your .`process-signs-direction-cove‌​r-button` element is not an ancestor of the element you click. You need to post more of your html structure (*the common ancestors of both elements if you want more help*)

Comment: I have added the HTML code structure as an image. If you look for Question Modified heading in original question.

Answer (score 1):

In your jquery part use  [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) instead of `toggleClass` .

```
 $(".processing-signs-direction-cover-sign-direction-selection-process").click(function() {
      $(this).closest("process-button.process-signs-direction-cover-button").addClass("process");
 });
```

Comment: This didn't worked. I have added the code structure as image